# Changing this code to Append instead of Overwrite (.Wav)

Tags: c++

As title saysw, i would like help with changing this code to instead of writing the buffer etc to a file, i would like it to append, so it created the file the first time, and then if the file exist it will append it.

```
template <typename T>
void write(std::ofstream& stream, const T& t) {
    stream.write((const char*)&t, sizeof(T));
}

template <typename T>
void writeFormat(std::ofstream& stream) {
    write<short>(stream, 1);
}

template <>
void writeFormat<float>(std::ofstream& stream) {
    write<short>(stream, 3);
}

template <typename SampleType>
void writeWAVData(
    char const* outFile,
    SampleType* buf,
    size_t bufSize,
    int sampleRate,
    short channels)
{
    std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::binary);
    stream.write("RIFF", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);
    stream.write("WAVE", 4);
    stream.write("fmt ", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 16);
    writeFormat<SampleType>(stream);                                // Format
    write<short>(stream, channels);                                 // Channels
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate);                                 // Sample Rate
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate * channels * sizeof(SampleType)); // Byterate
    write<short>(stream, channels * sizeof(SampleType));            // Frame size
    write<short>(stream, 8 * sizeof(SampleType));                   // Bits per sample
    stream.write("data", 4);
    stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);
    stream.write((const char*)buf, bufSize);
}
```

Here is the one line code for the process

```
writeWAVData("test.wav", mixBuffer.Array(), audioSampleSize, 48000, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line where you open the file to something like

```
std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
```

The `std::ios::app` flag stands for *append*. Refer to the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) for more details.

Comment: It does work, however it seems i was a bit naive, this will write the data, but the .wav file will not see the difference, as it will rewrite the header as well.

Would it be possible to rewrite the header with the newest information, so instead of saying (it's 2ms over and over), it will append, 2ms, 4ms, 6ms etc? (2ms is just a figure*)

Comment: Read back the wav file first and overwrite the file completely with the new data and updated header information.

Comment: It would be also good to know in what context you are using the `writeWAVData` function. If you are using it from the same application to just append wav data and create a file from it you could as well write it to a memory buffer first and create the file once appending has finished.

Comment: Could you show a way to do that?
If the duration is set somewhere i could also just add it each time, as the duration added should be the same all the time.

The Wav data comes from a buffer, from either mic or desktop, i don't think writing to a memory buffer is a good idea as the recording can be long.

Comment: Just implement a `readWAVData` function which opens the file for reading and read back all the stuff you write out in `writeWAVData`. Combine the read back buffer with your new data, add the sizes of old and new sample buffer and use `writeWAVData` to overwrite the file with the updated content. You have to remove the `std::ios::app` flag then of course.

Comment: that seems to be quite complicated, as i am not any good at this language. Wouldn't it just be possible to manually set the duration, the duration has to come from somewhere in the "writeWAVData", but i don't know where. Cause then i could probably solve it.

Comment: The duration is indirectly represented by the size of your data buffer `bufSize` and is written here `write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);` and here `stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);`. But even if you just increment the buffer size each time by the same amount you'd have to somehow merge the buffer which has already been written to the file with the one containing the new recorded data.

Comment: Ah okay, well i can say that i tried decoding the recordings with Raw Audio, forcing it to decode it ignoring the headers. But it was messed up no matter what, so seems i am not doing it completely right with the buffers.  Still the question is answered and you have been of great help, much appreciated!